# Cases, Pattern, Condition

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I supposed `Cases` would do the list produced as example

```
li = RandomSample[Range[100, 999], 30]
```

> ```
> {290, 651, 448, 970, 771, 185, 214, 691, 654, 608, 709, 130, 551, 315, 797, 701, 719, 633, 276, 888, 105, 879, 466, 853, 786, 976, 874, 907, 718, 798}
> ```

and filtered with

```
cli = Cases[li, {__, x_, y_, __} /; x < y]
```

I expected `{290, 651, 448, 970, 185, 214, 691, 608, 709,...}`
but received only

> ```
> {}
> ```

Obviously I did something wrong, but after trying to find something alike or consult help or making small variations to the function, I don't know why.

Comment: You are looking for elements that, among other things, are lists. There are no such elements.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  yes   true  I pretend only to filter cases where one element is lower than the following one ...  how to ask this condition without asking to be lists at the same time   ... I take out {} in patern it doesn't work neither

Comment: Both of these come close to what I think you want. `Flatten[Cases[Partition[li, 2, 1], {x_, y_} /; x < y]]

ReplaceList[li, {___, PatternSequence[x_, y_] /; x < y, ___} :> {x, 
   y}]` But there is an issue of repeats, when there is a consecutive triple with its two overlapping pairs satisfying the rule.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  yes   I tried, it's in this direction,   would try, Thank you, Me alone can not arrive to this complex expresion...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau --  You gave me the solution   I just take the first part of your expresion and made DeleteDuplicates  and the work is done!!   dlli = DeleteDuplicates[
  Flatten[Cases[Partition[li, 2, 1], {x_, y_} /; x < y]] ]

Comment: I thought about using `DeleteDuplicates` but the list might legitimately have duplicates. They could even appear adjacent to one another e.g. if input has a subsequence `33,48,38,51`.

Comment: @Anxon Is it possible that your list contains monotone sequences of numbers, like `{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3}`? What output do you expect to get in this case?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov , well not, it's made with the expresion I wrote up, RandomSample[Range[100,999],60] this expresion and others I made to make test for evaluating people they need to explain the rule that produces one list from another list here is this x,y are in son list if x<y   other selections are with different filters.   thanks for your help

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, in this case duplicates need to be deleted, because test shows first list ans then the filtered one. The key is to found the rule that is working. This idea cames after a play that learnt many years ago with french-cards, someone shows cards and the hand says yes or not abaut the card, the rest players need to guess the rule,   for instance odd after red, or black after black   or ....  ..  and also the OEIS site gave me many ideas. Thanks again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html):

```
SequenceCases[li, {x_, y_} /; x < y :> Sequence[x, y]]
```

> {290, 651, 448, 970, 185, 214, 608, 709, 130, 551, 315, 797, 701, 
>   719, 276, 888, 105, 879, 466, 853, 786, 976, 874, 907, 718, 798}

Comment: This is straight  I appreciate your teach. Yesterday make small portions of Danie’s expresión  and learn how to use partition and then cases... l and today with yours. You help me really,

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry I have not enough capacity to understaand abstraction as you have, I learn as I can. Daniel Lichblau help me, In one comment of you in this place you refered as solution, now I repeatedly read until found one important sentence   "... Cases looks elements not sublists ... " or this is my interpretation, Daniel cleverly broke list in a diferent list of pairs with Partition  and than HELP me, Also I read several times other options like ReplaceRepeatedly ... SequenceCases ...  finally SORRY   ... I learnt every time I meet a stone in middle way at darkness